# Complex grid with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I would like to make a design like this in CSS, but without the blank below blue div and with a margin between each.

I tried different things and impossible to do that, my divs always go to a new line...

Thank you very much !

[image]

Here is my code (simplified)

```css
.row > div { border: 1px solid black;}
.A {height:420px;}
.D {height:200px;}
.E {height:200px;}
.B {height:300px;}
.C {height:300px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 A">
        <div>
          A
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 B">
        <div>
          B
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 C">
        <div>
          C
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 D">
        <div>
          D
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 E">
        <div>
          E
        </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**With Flexbox there, no need to use bootstrap or grid!**

```css
.topmost-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sub-wrap-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0.5 1 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 0.125rem;
}

.inner-1 {
  flex: 0.7 1 0;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 0.0925rem;
  border-radius: 0.1825rem;
}

.inner-2 {
  flex: 0.3 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 0.0925rem;
}

.in-inner-1 {
  flex: 0.7 1 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-right: 0.0825rem;
  border-radius: 0.1825rem;
}

.in-inner-2 {
  flex: 0.3 1 0;
  background: lightsalmon;
  margin-left: 0.0825rem;
  border-radius: 0.1825rem;
}

.sub-wrap-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0.5 1 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0.125rem;
}

.inner-3 {
  flex: 0.5 1 0;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.0925rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.inner-4 {
  flex: 0.5 1 0;
  background: #3e3e3e;
  margin-top: 0.0925rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='topmost-wrapper'>


  <div class="sub-wrap-1">

    <div class="inner-1"></div>

    <div class="inner-2">
      <div class="in-inner-1"></div>
      <div class="in-inner-2"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class='sub-wrap-2'>

    <div class="inner-3"></div>
    <div class="inner-4"></div>

  </div>


</div>
```